# How to Cumulative Count in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
column1   Column2
A         01/01/2020
B         01/01/2020
C         04/01/2020
A         07/01/2020
B         07/01/2020
A         12/01/2020
C         10/01/2020
```

What I am trying to do is count how many times a value in column1 has occurred. So I want to be able to end up with this:

```
column1   Column2      column3
A         01/01/2020   1
B         01/01/2020   1
C         04/01/2020   1
A         07/01/2020   2
B         07/01/2020   2
A         12/01/2020   3
C         10/01/2020   2
```

I accomplished this is PowerBI thanks to some help but now I need to be able to do this in my query itself in SQL Server Managment Studio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
  SELECT Column1, Column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column2 ASC) AS Column3
  FROM table
  ORDER BY Column2 ASC, Column1 ASC
```